# Fetching Facebook graph API JSON value

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple PHP code that fetches Facebook graph API's value (total number of likes of a certain fanpage) via JSON. It works perfectly fine for the vast majority of fan pages but for 3 (out of 17 fan pages that I track) it simply can't read and print that value.

I don't understand where's the problem since the data I want to fetch is publicly available and the same code is applied for all pages.

Here's the code that prints correct value for a fan page with ID 214014840762:

```
<?php    
$currsiteurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/214014840762';  
$graph = json_decode(file_get_contents($currsiteurl));  
$currnofans = $graph->likes;  
echo "Number of likes: ".$currnofans; // prints out 107936    
?>
```

But if I simply change the ID to 160788560626000 or 167134649991034 the same code doesn't work anymore and it doesn't print anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe a privacy setting of the page?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what these pages are or what their URLs on Facebook are, so I can't verify this but, it's possible that your page is either not published (probably  not that likely), or (probably more likely) is age restricted.  The Facebook graph doesn't let you access a page's information if it is restricted by age.  Unfortunately, this is even true if you pass a Facebook application access token, or even an access token for a user who is over 18.  It's pretty stupid, and there have got to be at least 5 bug reports on bugs.developers.facebook.com for it.

**Update 6/13/2011**

Recently, Facebook made an update that requires you to use a valid user access token to pull information about a page.  This is a horrendous change, imo, but it is what it is.  Without a valid user access token, you will get a `false` or `error` response from every endpoint that isn't the basic info (root, `http://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>`) or `photos`, or `albums` endpoints.

So, if you're requested any of the other endpoints (`posts`, `feed`, `videos`, `statuses`, etc) you'll need to make sure you provide a *valid **user** access token* to access them.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm right then is the result an array and not a class 
so try something like $graph["likes"]

Comment: considering that it works for the other pages that are structured in the same way, I don't see how that could be the case.